# What will put more strain on eyes? 19" Monitor or 15" Laptop screen?

Tags: external-display, laptop-display, eye-strain

I have purchased 19" Dell Square Monitor (E1690S) with 1280x1024 resolution, so that I can easily look at the Source Code at a glance in Visual Studio and read other things well.

But, I am wondering, that looking at a bigger screen will put more light on the eyes than the smaller screen and put more strain.

Is it correct that a 19" Screen will put more strain on eyes rather than the 15" Laptop Screen in following cases:

1. Text size is equal on both.
2. Text size is larger on 19" and smaller on 15"

Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

More light does not mean more strain. If that was the case then you could never go outside.
(Compare sunlight intensity with the monitors. You will find that it is **a lot** more intense).

That means your premise is false.

As to strain due to other concerns: That depends on a lot of things, most of which are not mentioned in your post. Some examples (but no all of them) are:

- Quality of both screens (You mentioned which large screen but not which laptop screen, so there is nothing to compare the larger screen with).
- Distance to the screens (to far an the 19" will be a lot easier to read. Too close and you end up turning your head a lot. Distance to the screen(s) was not mentioned.
- Height of the screens. (top of your eyes should be near the top of the screen.)